# Testing Java or Silverlight plugins embedded in a page using Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

We have a product that defaults to a Java plugin to upload files, and then Silverlight after that if Java's not installed. There is a third fallback of a HTML 4 + JavaScript uploader, but I'd like to be able to automate the other two uploaders too.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Am I stuck with manual testing, or purchasing a product like TestComplete that could "see" the Java and Silverlight plugins?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem as faced by Aaron. Someone help !

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have four options

1. Purchase a commercial tool
2. Utilise the Windows UI automation API to automate the components, if they correctly implement the accessibility APIs
3. Manipulate the component by calling javascript directly
4. Do a dodgy workaround using tab and other sendkeys.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this but Selenium have introduce silverlight-selenium

http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/wiki/Fixtures

Download it from following link
http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/downloads/list